# Checkbox and php

Tags: php, html, post, checkbox

Please help.

I am trying to dynamically name my checkboxes using php. I am using POST.
The problem I am running in to is $element is not working. The results of $_POST
does not show any checkboxes.

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
foreach(array_keys($cart_array) as $element)
{ 
    print "<input type = 'checkbox' checked name = '{$element}' />";
}
```

But something like

```
foreach(array_keys($cart_array) as $element)
{ 
    print "<input type = 'checkbox' checked name = '$element}' />";
}
```

works just fine. Notice the missing { near $element}. This code would show which checkboxes are 
 on!! The printed array would have an extra "}"

```
Array
(
    [Tomato_and_Cheese_small] => on
    [Tomato_and_Cheese_small}] => 1
    [Tomato_and_Cheese_large] => on
    [Tomato_and_Cheese_large}] => 1
)
```

ps. there are other inputs like text that get posted to $_POST just fine.
    The print_r($cart_array) works fine too.

Comment: what are the contents of $cart_array? can you perform `print_r($cart_array)`?

Comment: and also, provide `print_r($_POST)`.

Comment: Array
(
    [Tomato_and_Cheese_small] => 2
    [Tomato_and_Cheese_large] => 1
)

Comment: In your question you mention radio buttons, in your code sample you print checkboxes. Which one is causing problems?

Comment: OK, I have one other thing that I need you to perform to give you accurate answer, can you perform `print_r($element)` inside the foreach loop, I need to be sure what it contains.

Comment: @kevin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301512/checkbox-and-php/7302304#7302304 you can accept it, but do not insert your answer into question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser *sends* the value of radio buttons only when they are checked.

Also, each radio button must have the same name (if you want to user to be able to check only one of them). Only the value changes:

```
print '<input type=checkbox checked value="'.htmlspecialchars($element).'" name=checked_items />';
```

POST this and check the value of `$_POST['checked_items']`

Comment: @ arnaud sorry, I was trying to say checkboxes and not radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If a checkbox is not checked it will not be present in the post parameters.

Comment: Thanks. It is a checkbox that I am having trouble with and not the radiobutton.

Answer (score 0):

What happened was that he had checkboxes with the name $element and text fields with the same name too after that. So the checkbox name $element in $_POST got overrided by the text field $element